# How should one test matplotlib plotting with tox and py.test?

Tags: python, matplotlib, pytest, tox

How should one test matplotlib plotting with tox and py.test?

My files are:

```
testtox /
  - testtox.py
  - tox.ini
  - setup.py
```

testtox.py contains:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


def plotting():
    """Plot.

    Examples
    --------
    >>> plt.ion()
    >>> plotting()

    """
    plt.plot([1, 2, 1, 3])
```

tox.ini:

```
[tox]
envlist = py27

[testenv:py27]
sitepackages = True
commands = py.test --doctest-modules testtox.py
deps = pytest
```

setup.py:

```
from setuptools import setup

setup(name='testtox', py_modules=['testtox'])
```

py.test on its own works ok:

```
$ py.test --doctest-modules testtox.py
```

In this case the plot window is briefly flashed.

tox produces an error on the DISPLAY variable:

```
$ tox
[...cut ...]
=================================================== FAILURES ====================================================
__________________________________________ [doctest] testtox.plotting ___________________________________________
005     """Plot.
006 
007     Examples
008     --------
009     >>> plt.ion()
010     >>> plotting()
UNEXPECTED EXCEPTION: RuntimeError(u'Invalid DISPLAY variable',)
Traceback (most recent call last):
[...]

  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_qt5.py", line 138, in _create_qApp
    raise RuntimeError('Invalid DISPLAY variable')

RuntimeError: Invalid DISPLAY variable
```

This error happened with the most recent version of tox (2.1.1). An older version did not produce the error.

Comment: Another option would be to mock out the actual plotting, and just test that your code makes the appropriate calls

Comment: Would mockup have a meaning with doctest?

Comment: There's a library specifically for that: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/MiniMock

Comment: But the user reading the docstring will not see the plot if it is mocked.

Comment: The user reading the docstring text won't see the plot either way!

Comment: :-) But when the user executes the docstring it should show the plot. At least that what would be most natural to me.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82918/discussion-between-jonrsharpe-and-finn-arup-nielsen).

Answer (score 0):

Setting the DISPLAY environment variable in `tox.ini` seems to do the trick in this case:

```
[tox]
envlist = py27

[testenv:py27]
setenv = 
    DISPLAY = :0
sitepackages = True
commands = py.test --doctest-modules testtox.py
deps = pytest
```